# No Module named error despite Module existing in the package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, python-packaging

My project structure is as follows :

[image]

When I run the following code using

```
python driver.py --job=dataPrepartion.dataIngestion  XX XX XX
```

**I get an error "No Module named custlogger"** (screenshot attahed)

[image]
However custlogger.py file is present in "dataPrepartion" folder (Please see the project structure image).
Also if I run the code directly using

```
python dataIngestion.py XX XXX XX
```

The code works just fine. Now if I change the import statement in dataIngestion.py to

```
import dataPrepartion.custlogger as logg
```

The code works from

```
python driver.py --job=dataPrepartion.dataIngestion  XX XX XX
```

However now it doesn't run from

```
python dataIngestion.py XX XXX XX
```

And throws module not found error.

**Is there any way in which import statement can be made independent so that it doesn't throw error from which script the code is called.**